# Can I end something early when a bug is detected using .catch?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I code a discord bot and one of the commands DMs another user but if the bot cant DM that user an error occurs, but the bot says "Message sent successfully" and gives the 5 minute cooldown. I want to know if I can make it so that when an error happens on DMing the user, if the bot cant DM, it will say "Error: Cannot DM this user" and then stop, without giving the 5 minute cooldown on the command.

The way I have it now will say it cant DM that user, but will also say that the message was sent successfully and give the cooldown.

```
        if (!user)
            return message.channel.send(
                'Who would you like to send this strongly worded message to?'
            );
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Message received from ${message.author.username}.`)
            .setDescription('You are a huge poopy stinky!!!!!!!!');
        var sent = true;
        user.send(embed).catch(err => {
            sent = false;
            if (sent == false)
                return message.channel.send(`Sorry, an error occured: ${err}`);
            return;
        });
        message.channel.send('Message sent Successfuly.');

        cooldowns.set(`${message.author.id}-strongmsg`, Date.now() + ms('5m'));

        setTimeout(() => {
            botcooldown.delete(message.channel.id);
        }, 3000);
    }
```

user = the mentioned user

Comment: Wrap your function in a try catch block and add your "what to do if error" logic in the catch block. With promises you can use async await to achieve this. Its simpler than using .then .catch.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to use a try catch block, could you explain a bit? Im somewhat new to javascript.

Comment: Look it up. We always suggest doing some research before asking questions. Learn about try/catch [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Thanks I tried

`try {
  let user = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (!user)
   return message.channel.send(
    'Who would you like to send this strongly worded message to?'
   );
  let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle(`Message received from ${message.author.username}.`)
   .setDescription('You are a huge poopy stinky!!!!!!!!');
  var sent = true;
  user.send(embed);
} catch (error) {
  message.channel.send(`Sorry an error occured. ${error}`)
  return;
}`
Bot logged error in the console and said message sent successfully. But did not say the error @Elitezen

Comment: If you have new code and still need help post a new question